# Using If Large Statement and Populating Remainder of Table in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement

I have a dataset that looks like the example below. I want to pull a list of the last ten transactions, ordered by Transaction Date, while capturing all columns of information in the original dataset; and I want to do this only IF the Salesman is Jimmy.

I'm stumped. Any ideas how to do this?

Example dataset below:

```
    Customer Name   Customer Group  Salesman    Transaction Date
    Sam                    1          Jimmy     3/21/2015
    Jill                   2          Johnny    3/21/2015
    Scott                  3          Joanny    3/21/2015
    Sean                   4          Slippy    3/24/2015
    Dave                   5          Slappy    3/25/2015
    Amber                  4          Slummy    3/26/2015
    Shawn                  3          Jimmy     3/24/2015
    Matt                   2          Johnny    3/26/2015
    Matthew                4          Joanny    3/24/2015
    Mark                   3          Slippy    3/21/2015
    Luke                   2          Slappy    3/26/2015
    John                   1          Slummy    3/26/2015
    Jonathan               5          Jimmy     3/24/2015
    Zach                   3          Johnny    3/26/2015
    Asher                  2          Joanny    3/21/2015
```

Desired output is of last 10 transactions ordered by Forecast Transaction Date

```
Customer Name   Customer Group  Salesman    Forecast Transaction Date
```

Update:

I'm using this formula, mimicking Scott's but its erroring out.

```
=iferror(index(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[[#Headers],[Opportunity Name]]:index(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Opportunity Name],match(1E+99,All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date])),aggregate(15,6,row(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[[#Headers],[Forecast Close Date]]:index(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date],match(1E+99,All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date]))-3)/((All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[[#Headers],[Pegasus Stage]]:index(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Pegasus Stage],match(1E+99,All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date]))="Closed Affirmative - Contract Signed")*(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[[#Headers],[Forecast Close Date]]:index(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date],match(1E+99,All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date]))='MDA-JV'!V10)),countif('MDA-JV'!$V$10:'MDA-JV'!$V10,'MDA-JV'!V10))),"")
```

Comment: In the desired output section, ignore the "forecast" part. Should just be Transaction Date

Comment: Though I have answered with formula, this can be done with Advanced Filter.  See [HERE](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2014/08/07/top-5-items-in-advanced-filter-list/)

Comment: I am using PowerQuery to pull Salesforce reports. From this data I am building dashboards, one of which contains this table so I think the formula route works best.

Comment: You response posing as an answer is likely to be removed so I've added it to your question. Most importantly, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @Jeeped. Yeah, I posted as an answer due to char limit. I'm using 2010.

Comment: The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. If is much better than `LARGE(IF(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine takes a slightly different tack than @Jeeped.  Though I did steal the INDEX/MATCH that allows the ranges to grow and contract to the correct size automatically.

Putting the name of the Salesperson desired in L1 and starting with the Transaction Date.  To get the Transaction dates in order:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,$D$2:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,D:D))/($C$2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,D:D))=$L$1),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

`
And copy down 10 rows.

Then then customer name refers to the Transaction Date which I put in Column I:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,D:D)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,D:D)))/(($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,D:D))=$L$1)*($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1E+99,D:D))=I2)),COUNTIF($I$2:$I2,I2))),"")
```

The Salesman column is a simple refernce to L1.

To get the Group I used a simple SUMIFS():

```
=IF(I2<>"",SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,F2,C:C,H2,D:D,I2),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

This will order the entries by date starting with the newest.

Comment: fwiw, I've found that using full column references for INDEX (e.g. `INDEX(A:A, ...`) does not negatively impact the performance of the formula so long as the rows being computed by AGGREGATE are truncated to the extent of the data. One less thing to adjust.

Comment: @Jeeped went ahead a stole it for this one too.  Thanks for the information.  It makes sense and will help for dynamic datasets.

Comment: @Scott Craner --thanks for your help here. To pull values for Transaction Date I simplified things by just using a LARGE IF function. That seemed to work well. I tried using your formula for Customer Name but its giving me the wrong customer name. Does it matter that the source data and table I'm building are on different sheets? Not sure why its not working.

Comment: @sqlbg it probably has to do with the Row() part of the formula, it needs to start at 1 so if your range starts on row 2 you will need to subtract 1.

Comment: Something's still not working. I'm mimicking your formula but its erorring out now.

Comment: @sqlbg Interesting, I promise that I did not photoshop the above.  What escle are you using?

Comment: @sqlbg try this formula, it is untested but based on your formula `=IFERROR(INDEX(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Opportunity Name],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date])-1)/((All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Pegasus Stage]="Closed Affirmative - Contract Signed")*(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date]='MDA-JV'!V10)),COUNTIF('MDA-JV'!$V$10:$V10,'MDA-JV'!V10))),"")`

Answer (score 1):

The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can return successive matching row numbers to the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

With *jimmy* in H2, put this standard formula in F2

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A, MATCH(1E+99,$D:$D )))/($C$1:INDEX($C:$C, MATCH(1E+99,$D:$D ))=$H2), ROW(1:1)))
```

Copy to G2 and I2 then fill down as necessary.

[image: jimmy_orders]

Use the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to avoid displaying `#NUM!` errors when you run out of matches to return.

This is based on the sort order of the original data. If you want to reverse the sort order change the 15 (AGGREGATE's [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) sub-function) to 14 (AGGREGATE's [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) sub-function). If the original data is unsorted and you require sorted results, then you need to first get the smallest date using similar pseudo-SMALLIF function and then use that in a multiple criteria to retrieve the other matching columns, adjusting for duplicate dates if necessary.

**Addendum for [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx) tables**

To start off, rename your table temporarily while you develop the formula. While its current name (e.g. *All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2*) may be necessary to identify it for other purposes, all it does now is obfuscate the formula; essentially hiding small errors that might otherwise be immediately apparent. To this end, I have renamed your table **aimf2**. As soon as formula development is complete, it can be renamed back to its original and all references will be immediately updated.

As per the following image the formulas in I4:L4 are,

```
=INDEX(aimf2[Customer Name], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(aimf2[Customer Name])-ROW(aimf2[#Headers]))/((aimf2[Salesman]=$G$3)*(aimf2[Transaction Date]=L4)), COUNTIF(L$4:L4, L4)))
=INDEX(aimf2[Customer Group], AGGREGATE(15, 6, (ROW(aimf2[Customer Name])-ROW(aimf2[#Headers]))/((aimf2[Salesman]=$G$3)*(aimf2[Transaction Date]=L4)), COUNTIF(L$4:L4, L4)))
=PROPER($G$3)
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, aimf2[Transaction Date]/(aimf2[Salesman]=$G$3), ROW(1:1))
```

Add error control if desired and fill down for ten rows.

[image: jimmy_sales_two]
               <sup>[Sample worksheet](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Using%20If%20Large%20Statement%20and%20Populating%20Remainder%20of%20Table%20in%20Excel.xlsx) with ListObject tables</sup>