# Index Match to Large IF Statement

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I have a dataset from which I am attempting to grab the 10 most recent results. I successfully used a LARGE IF function to select the appropriate dates of the results. However, I now need to grab other data points associated with those dates from the dataset. The LARGE IF function I am using is and this is what's populating the Closed Date column.

I assume I would use an index function of some sort to get values such as Teammate and Type. Not sure how to proceed though. Thoughts?

```
{=LARGE(IF(All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Pegasus Stage]="Closed Affirmative - Contract Signed",All_Incremental_MDA_JV_Forecast__2[Forecast Close Date],""),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10})}



Oppty Name  Group   Teammate    Type    Close Date
                                        17-Mar-16
                                        15-Mar-16
                                        11-Mar-16
                                        11-Mar-16
                                        11-Mar-16
                                        11-Mar-16
                                        9-Mar-16
                                        9-Mar-16
                                        24-Feb-16
                                        22-Feb-16
```

Comment: And the answers from your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36337388/using-if-large-statement-and-populating-remainder-of-table-in-excel/36337958#36337958) did not work?

Comment: I would use a pivot table. Please search top 10 results in pivot table on youtube.

Comment: If you use a pivot table how do you show the 10 most recent records judged by the Transaction Date? This is the issue I was coming across.

Comment: If using a PivotTable, you need to write some code to filter it on the 10 most recent records, and trigger the code automatically on PivotTable Refresh. But that's the solution I would use.

Comment: Could you point me to any such code? Googling and couldn't find anything.